# Spring @SessionAttributes returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-annotations

Im trying to use @SessionAttributes in my controller class as follows:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"calMethods", "taxList"})
@RequestMapping("/secure")
public class reportController extends BaseController {

//..
@ModelAttribute("taxList")
    public List<multiCalDto> getTaxList() {
        return new ArrayList<multiCalDto>();
    }
//....

@RequestMapping(value = "/confirmCal.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView launchconfirmCal(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("seqNo") String seqNo) {
    ...........

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("confirmCalView");
    modelAndView.addObject("taxList", calBean.getTaxList());
    return modelAndView;
      }


@RequestMapping(value = "/executeCalPay.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView executeCalPay(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("taxList") List<multiCalDto> taxList) {
      // ............



      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("calView");
      System.out.println("taxList -- "+taxList);
      return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

I added taxList in launchconfirmCal() and trying to access the same in executeCalPay(). 
I tried to print taxList before adding to modelAttribute and the size is 12 and when I retireve in executeCalPay() it shows null.
I am not changing its value in JSP.

Comment: does your calMethods attribute work ?

Comment: Try  this @SessionAttributes(value = {"calMethods", "taxList"})

Comment: @ Sandeep Rao..no it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment out this method and retry

```
@ModelAttribute("taxList")
    public List<multiCalDto> getTaxList() {
        return new ArrayList<multiCalDto>();
    }
```

@ModelAttribute annotated methods are called before **ALL** request mapping methods, so it resets your taxList before the post method is called

Comment: I am getting the foll exception when its commented out :org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute 'taxList'

Comment: Are you using it in any other method signature?

Comment: You cannot have a non-initialized session attribute as @ModelAttribute in method signatures. that's why. It can't be null

Comment: remove them fro method signatures and if needed initialize them explicitly in the method bodies

Comment: i did not get you. Can you help me understanding.

Comment: When using session attributes, you can add them to method signatures only if they have been already initialized (not null). So, except from the post method where the attribute is already initialized, (by the launchconfirmCal method) in all every other request mapping method that you have a @ModelAttribute argument of taxList, remove it from the method signature and set is as model.addAttribute(new new ArrayList<multiCalDto>());  in the first line of the method.

Comment: I cannot do that. If I initialise them in each method then I would not get the seesion value right?

Comment: According to current implementation, if they break means that the session value is null. If not that it is what the model attribute method returns, that is  new ArrayList<multiCalDto>();

Comment: you won't initialize it t the post method. Its where you need it and it will be already holding the value you set in the get method